# Angular 12, уведомления и ошибки в консоли, не могу отследить источник

Tags: angular2

логирование и ошибки в консоли, прилетают из main.js скомпилированного чанка, как я могу настроить, чтоб я мог видеть источник дев среды? Angular 12

Как ожидаю получить:

[image: Как ожидаю получить]

Как сейчас:

[image: Как сейчас]

Comment: ng serve запускает скомпилированный билд :/

Comment: при инициализации проекта, все было нормально, на ангуляре 11, затем поднял версии до 12.2.1

Comment: Значить дебажить надо ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема была в angular.json, при повышении версии видимо "испачкался", из
configurations, пропали конфиги development

```
   "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
```